# why kendo grid mvc automatically truncate decimal type after 8 decimal point

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

why telerik **GridModel** class truncate(or better to say Roundup) my decimal type after 8 decimal digit

forexample with database value of : 123.12345678 the Grid result is 123.123456**8**

i use normal telerik with entity framework database first and has a right value in database

```
type in C#: decimal
type in SQL: numeric(25,15)
```

Comment: Is number declared as a double, single, or decimal?

Comment: @jdweng in C# decimal and in sql server numeric(25,15)

Comment: That is binary places and not decimal places.  See IEEE-754 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754  You must have a binary 32 bit which is 7.22 accuracy or decimal 32 which is 7 bit accuracy

Comment: but they are functionally equivalent, and value in the database has exact 123.12345678 and i can set i even more like 123.123456789 but again in UI it is 123.1234568